# Can control fields be formed with more than three portals?

Tags: ingress

My local area has more active players on the enemy team, so we have to take what we can get.  After a recent attack, several of our key links broke, and the enemy owns many portals but hasn't started linking them yet.  The outer links that once formed our control fields remain, though, all but one.  If I relink that one to form an enclosed area again, will that become a control field?

To clarify, portals A and B are linked, B and C are linked, C and D are linked, and D and E are linked; and A through E roughly describe a circle.  If I link E to A in order to close the circle, will the circle become a control field?

Portals B through D are a long way out of my way, and re-forming the interior links would be very difficult on my tight holiday time schedule.

Comment: dat downvote T_T oh well.  It's useful info.  I honestly thought that just closing the wall would be enough, that more than three links could be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I keep answering my own questions.  After work I made the walk to E and linked A from there;  it formed a closed polygon but failed to form a control field.  Just closing the shape isn't enough, it **must be a triangle formed from three links and three portals**.

D wasn't actually that far from E, and there was a random key for B lying on the road between A and E, so I linked what all I could and recovered part of the area we had before, mostly the outer edges so the enemy can't block us from finishing our links (at least, without just blowing up the portals again :D ).  Only problem is that my owned portal - A - is now being used as the main lynchpin, and it's weak (I just hit level 3 today), so we're likely to lose these fields again, but hey, more AP for me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget using the fields to form layers! If you layer it up you'll have a strong protection for the inner portal control. Around here we've battled back and forth, and at one point there was a nine layer "cake" of fields that the opposing faction let stand for a few days due to the complexity of trying to take the network down.

Comment: It sounds interesting, but what are you calling "layers" exactly ?

Comment: @Anto The fields, you can cover a central field with multiple fields over top of it. Meaning worst case,you lose the small field in the middle, and best case, if your "top" (last) field is too large for them to break, everything contained inside will remain neutral at your leisure. If you take the time you can also link additional portals to the edges of your fields as you expand boosting that portal's strength if I recall correctly. [Here's an example](http://i0.wp.com/decodeingress.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Article-ingress-onion-fields-new.png?resize=702%2C465)